# Spring Batch UNKNOWN state

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Have a batch which does some heavy operations. It runs for approximately 11-12 hours.
After that it moves to UNKNOWN state.

I have a question when would a batch move to UNKNOWN state?

Following is stack Trace.

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back JDBC transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Protocol violation
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doRollback(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:285)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:845)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:822)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.rollbackOnException(TransactionTemplate.java:161)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:134)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:264)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:76)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:367)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:214)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:143)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:284)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:195)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:135)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:61)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:144)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:124)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:282)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:121)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:909)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Protocol violation
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive
```

Thanks
Aditya

Comment: Do you have an error message?

Comment: Hi Following is exit message I get.

org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back JDBC transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Protocol violation...

Comment: Add full stack trace to question!

Comment: Is it the entire stacktrace? I think there should be something more to it. Also as Michael pointed out in the answer, you may need to investigate why the rollback was unsuccessful.

Comment: Thanks guys for responses. The rollback was being unsuccessful because of some JDBC jar version mismatch.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A batch job will move into the UNKNOWN state only when a rollback is unsuccessful, leaving the job in an uncertain state which is what it looks like happened here.  The real question here is…why was the rollback unsuccessful?

Answer (score 1):

Check `org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep`. It is full of:

```
try {
    getJobRepository().updateExecutionContext(stepExecution);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    stepExecution.setStatus(BatchStatus.UNKNOWN);
    exitStatus = exitStatus.and(ExitStatus.UNKNOWN);
    stepExecution.addFailureException(e);
}
```

So it happens on `update*` operations of `getJobRepository()` (same as @Minella stated).